# Spark performance optimization

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

My spark application compare two huge dataframes and saves the result to disk. I have 3 different comparisons on same dataframes and do union all to get output dataframe, so in shuffle phase spark writes same dataframes 3 times to memory and in shuffle read phase spark read size is 3 times the actual dataframes size. So here spark does the comparisions 3 times on same dataframes.
i tried doing persisting the dataframes before comparision, so that it doesnot need to shuffle write 3 times but my job failes with timeout error, eventhough my 2 dataframes fits into the memory.

how can i control the shuffle write/read to maximize the performance? Here my input data is parquet format, so directly creating dataframe with input data, here is pseudo code, i have temp tables from input DFs

```
df_comp = sqlContext.sql("SELECT a.* FROM tab1 a LEFT OUTER JOIN tab2 b on a.id==b.id WHERE b.id IS null \
UNION ALL \
SELECT b.* FROM tab1 a RIGHT OUTER JOIN tab2 b on a.id==b.id WHERE a.id IS null \
UNION ALL \
SELECT b.* FROM tab2 b JOIN tab1 a On b.id==a.id or b.RCPNT_ID != a.RCPNT_ID")
```

Comment: Can you please share the relevant code with us?  I don't quite understand what "comparisons" you are doing.

Comment: It looks to me like you're attempting a full outer join.  Do you want to give that a try?

Comment: Nope, the actual comparison yields just 2% from both the tables.

Comment: In your Spark UI, in the stage of the Joins how many partitions this process is using? Is that 200? Or is more partitions?

Comment: It is doing total 600, so 200/join